# Xamarin Firebase iOS not receiving FCM messages

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I tried to implement Firebase push notifications and messages in my Xamarin Forms application. In Android it works fine, while in iOS I am receiving push notifications but I'm not receiving FCM data-only messages.

I am using Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging package, and I followed [this guide](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/docs/Firebase/CloudMessaging/GettingStarted.md#receive-messages) and [this other one](https://xamarinlatino.com/xamarin-forms-firebase-cloud-messaging-ios-setup-1961a91d4055) too.

This is my AppDelegate.cs code:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, IMessagingDelegate
{
    //
    // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
    // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
    // visible.
    //
    // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
    //
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        Forms.SetFlags("Brush_Experimental");
        Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
        //Ascetic.Plugins.PopupDecorations.iOS.PrettyPopup.Init();
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        SfListViewRenderer.Init();
        new Syncfusion.SfAutoComplete.XForms.iOS.SfAutoCompleteRenderer();
        Syncfusion.XForms.iOS.TabView.SfTabViewRenderer.Init();
        iOSMaterialFrameRenderer.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        // Register your app for remote notifications.
        configureFirebase();


        var result = base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        app.KeyWindow.TintColor = UIColor.White;
        foreach (var fs in UIFont.FamilyNames.OrderBy(c => c).ToList())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" * " + fs);
            foreach (var f in UIFont.FontNamesForFamilyName(fs).OrderBy(c => c).ToList())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" *-- " + f);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void configureFirebase()
    {
        Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
        {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

            // iOS 10 or later
            var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) =>
            {
            });

            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;
        }
        else
        {
            // iOS 9 or before
            var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
            var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
        }
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
    }

    //Firebase
    [Export("messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:")]
    public void DidReceiveRegistrationToken(Messaging messaging, string fcmToken)
    {
        Preferences.Set("tokenNotifica", fcmToken);
        Console.WriteLine("\nValue: " + (fcmToken));
    }

    //APP IN BACKGROUND
    public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        handleNotification(userInfo);
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
    }

    [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification,
    Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        handleNotification(notification.Request.Content.UserInfo);
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
    }

    [Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action
    completionHandler)
    {
        completionHandler();
        NSDictionary userInfo = response.Notification.Request.Content.UserInfo;
        try
        {
            var Data = userInfo[new NSString("gcm.notification.data")] as NSString;
            if (Data != null && Data != "")
            {
                string[] tokens = Data.ToString().Split(',');
                string Username = tokens[0];
                string Password = tokens[1];
                var Title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Notification.Request.Content.Title) ? "No Notification available" : response.Notification.Request.Content.Title;
                var Body = string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Notification.Request.Content.Body) ? "No Message available" : response.Notification.Request.Content.Body;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    [Export("messaging:didReceiveMessage:")]
    public void DidReceiveMessage(Messaging messaging, RemoteMessage message)
    {
        handleNotification(message.AppData);
    }

    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        Messaging.SharedInstance.ApnsToken = deviceToken;
    }

    public void ApplicationReceivedRemoteMessage(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

The *DidReceiveRegistrationToken* method is called with the token. If I send a notification to that token the method DidReceiveRemoteNotification is called, and the notification is successfully shown by the device. But if I send a data-only message to that token, nothing is called.

I tried disabling swizzling, enabling it, reconfigure Firebase from scratch and delete and recreate certificates and provisioning profiles in the Apple Dev website, but nothing worked. Also, I think all is configured correctly since my app is receiving notifications.

I hope I gave enough information, I am struggling with this for weeks

**EDIT**

I use this function in php to send the data-only message to devices

```
function sendMessage($deviceKey, $data){
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type: application/json", 
        "project_id: ***",
        "Authorization: key=***"
    ));

    // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    ]);

    $body = [
        'to'  => $deviceKey,
        "data" => $data
    ];

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($body));
    $res = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $res;
}
```

This function is equal to the function that send the notification, but the $body array doesn't contain a "notification" key.
What I would like to do is use the data payload of the message in the application without display the notification, and this works just fine in Android, but not in iOS.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean the **data-only message**? You could share some sample data to explain that.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Hi, thanks for the reply! I have just updated the question.

Comment: Thanks for updating. And whether the iOS device can not receive data type 
remote notification both in the background or foreground?

Comment: Here are some good dicussions about not receiving firebase messages in iOS. You could have a look at that. [One](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/335), [another](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1041).